# Getting 'possible missing firmware error messages' after kernel related updates

Tags: kernel, updates, firmware, i915

In Ubuntu 16.10 I am getting the following error messages when I do kernel related updates:

```
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_guc_ver9_14.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/bxt_guc_ver8_7.bin for module i915
```

Everything seems to work on my Lenovo Yoga 3 Pro, but it would be good to know what this means and if I need to worry about it.

Comment: There is nothing to worry about.

Comment: Pilot is correct, nothing to worry about.

Comment: I'm affected, too. I've come to this by a recent issue that my hibernation had stopped working after some common OS updates (Xubuntu 16.10), before It's been working for years... Now I am unable to hibernate.

Calling "pm-hibernate" makes the system freeze :( Could it be related?

Answer (score 1):

## It's not a bug...

These are Intel drivers for future Integrated Graphics Processors (GPUs) that are not yet released to the public and are still in development. For example GuC v9.14 is for Kabylake and GuC v8.7 is for Broxton.

On my system for example I see:

```
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.8.1-040801-generic
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_dmc_ver1_01.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_guc_ver9_14.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/bxt_guc_ver8_7.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/skl_guc_ver6_1.bin for module i915
```

Even when the GPU is released and the binary files are released it still won't make a difference to your platform because it won't have the new GPU anyway.

This question has been asked a few times in AskUbuntu and there are various bug reports floating around the internet but they all answers say it's not a cause for concern.